# Failed to install sklearn via pip install Using Mac OS

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using python3.7 and I want to install sklearn package via `pip3 install`.

I already have the dependencies like numpy and scipy installed.

So, when I use `sudo pip3 install -U scikit-learn` the error occurred

```
Command "/usr/local/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-req-build-d3203b5n/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-7wbr9qu2/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-req-build-d3203b5n/
```

I don't know what went wrong, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem and I solved it using

```
pip install git+https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git
```

Before run this command, check if you have already installed numpy and scipy packages.